# I work on Android Studio-dart-flutter while running the app and simulator is on there is error showing up says build failed Could not open settings

Tags: flutter, dart

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception`.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '`C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\flutter_course_1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe)`.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '`_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61`

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Switch your Java version to a compaitable version 
To switch it ,you have to set your PATH.
   https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html